# Count horizontal And Vertical line In Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Can Any One Help me For Counting Number of Horizontal And Vertical Line in Image

This is for Part of Feature Extraction Project For OCR

Thx a lot

More Information :

" My Project is Finding Number in Image So its OCR Project

im gona Use Neural Network in Matlab

But My Problem Is what Feature should i Send To Network "

Comment: What stage are you at, can you show what you have tried?

Comment: what line finding methods have you used so far?

Comment: i started by reading some documents like 'A Matlab Project in Optical Character Recognition (OCR) By Jesse Hansen' but about project im in stgage that Characters Are Segmented And Ready For Feature Extraction

Comment: About Method i know that there is hough method but Have No Idea how to count Horizontal And Vertical Line By This Method

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting out and have no idea what to do take a look at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850717/what-are-some-popular-ocr-algorithms

This is implemented in C#.

Here is a project that does OCR, may also be useful to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160868/A-C-Project-in-Optical-Character-Recognition-OCR-U

Or this may be some use, after searching a while Tesseracts seemed to be relevant:

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.01-1.exe&can=2&q=

Goodluck